# Kotlin error Could not parse the Android Application Module's Gradle config. Resolve gradle build issues and/or resync

Tags: firebase, android-studio, kotlin

**After updating the Android Studio to latest while connecting to the Firebase below error is coming.**

```
Could not parse the Android Application Module's Gradle config. Resolve gradle build issues and/or resync.
```

**Project Gradle:-**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.32"
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Have you tried updating the kotlin version?

Comment: Yes, its upto date

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after googling i found the solution. I have removed below line from Module Gradle and it worked.

**testImplementation 'junit:junit:'**